# When are my BindableProperties ready to read?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm instantiating a class in XAML, and trying to initialize properties via bindable properties.

I've noticed that those properties aren't ready to read by the time the constructor runs. I wasn't really expecting them to, but I did then expect to see some kind of OnReady that I could override that runs when the XAML is done processing.

If I wait until OnParentSet runs, then I can see my properties, but that doesn't seem like guaranteed behaviour. And I can't seem to find anything else to override that would provide that behaviour.

MyPage.XAML:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <local:MyClass MyVar="123">
        </local:MyClass>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

MyClass.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MyClass : ContentView
{
    public string MyVar { get { return (string)GetValue(MyClass.MyVarProperty); } set { SetValue(MyClass.MyVarProperty, value); } }
    public static readonly BindableProperty MyVarProperty = BindableProperty.Create("MyVar", typeof(string), typeof(MyClass), default(string));

    public MyClass() : base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Debug.WriteLine(MyVar); // null, or whatever default is
    }

    protected override void OnParentSet()
    {
        base.OnParentSet();

        Debug.WriteLine(MyVar); // "123"! ... but can I rely on OnParentSet?
    }
}
```

Is there some way of getting code to run after all my properties have been set from the XAML? Am I even doing this right?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your intent, but usually the idea of BindableProperties is to react to changes. BindableProperties are designed to fire events/methods when they change, why not use those events/methods?

Comment: @deckertron_9000 Well, if that's true, why do we assign to them in XAML, which is static? Or is there some other kind of property I should be using for that kind of use case?

Comment: You define them in xaml to give them an initial value. That assignment in xaml still constitutes a value change event in the xaml.cs instance class. If you add more detail on what you're trying to achieve with this property I'd be glad to help :)

Comment: Really I just want to be able to use them to initialize values for my class instance, in XAML. And I want to deal with several of them in one initialization function, in which case I have to be sure they're all loaded. It'll allow me to avoid more extraneous function calls which may impact performance slightly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I get what you're doing. The xaml snippet is actually part of something greater, like:

```xml
<ContentPage ...>
   <ContentPage.Content>
       <local:MyClass MyVar="123" />
   </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

What the Xaml Parser does here is, in that order:

- instantiate MyClass
- assign 123 to the BindableProperty MyVarProperty of the MyClass instance
- assign the MyClass instance to the Page.Content

Assigning "123" to MyVar IS NOT part of the process of constructing `MyClass`, but part of the process of constructing the `ContentPage`. Write the equivalent c# code, and you'll figure that out.

If you want 123 to be assigned at the time the MyClass.InitializeComponent() is invoked, you should make the assignment as part of the MyClass xaml, like in

```xml
<ContentView ... x:Class="MyNS.MyClass"
    MyVar="123" />
</ContentView>
```

Comment: Since the instantiation and the assignment are done together in the same line of XAML, I was assuming that the equivalent code would be: new MyClass() { MyVar="123" }; My goal is to have classes defined in code, and instantiated with configuration values from xml. I guess Xamarin.Forms just doesn't see it that way. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my question, adding more of the XAML snippet. I like to keep SO questions abstract, maybe too abstract sometimes.

Comment: it is actually strictly equivalent to `new MyClass() { MyVar="123" };`. You can not expect MyVar to be set before the control leaves the constructor.

Comment: You're right, I'm actually new to using that instantiation pattern and was under the impression that the values get set before the constructor is called.